# openCV 3.1 imread.empty() - always empty if relative path, breaks if not

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opencv, imread

I've recently began to use Visual Studio 2015 to work with OpenCV (being guided by tutorial), but I can't get this working. So the problem is, if I specify the location of file relatively (just use "imageName.extens" as an argument) and run the program from the VS, `image.empty()` is always `true`. I tried *.jpg, *.bmp, *.png - still the same.

When I specify the location exactly via keeping it in String, it shows a window and then crashes. The same happens when I run application via cmd.
I have read that people had this issue with `image.empty()` when they mixed debug and relase libraries, but it is not a case - I have specified libraries for debug and release in appriopriate property sheet.

I have no more ideas with it, I've been fighting with that for days, I would really appreciate some help. I even upgraded from 2.4 to 3.1, thinking it might have been an issue. It was not. Thank you in advance, a lot.

Here is the code:

```
#include <opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
if (argc != 2)
{
    cout << " Usage: display_image ImageToLoadAndDisplay" << endl;
    return -1;
}
else if (argc > 1) {
    cout << argv[1] << endl;
}

Mat image;
image = imread(argv[1], CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR); // Read the file  IMREAD_COLOR

if (image.empty()) // Check for invalid input
{
    cout << "Could not open or find the image" << std::endl;
    return -1;
}

namedWindow("Display window", WINDOW_NORMAL); // Create a window for display.
imshow("Display window", image); // Show our image inside it.

//waitKey(0); // Wait for a keystroke in the window - doesnt work
getchar();
getchar();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: you could `printf(getcwd())` to see if the current directory is really the one you're expecting.

Comment: Thank you, I was actually using wrong location to store my pictures. The proper one is ...\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\ConsoleApplication2\ConsoleApplication2 not as I thought the directory with the executable: ..\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\ConsoleApplication2\x64\Release.

Now, having this solved - any idea why it crashes?

Comment: that's a totally different question. What does the debugger say?

Comment: Solved. Forgive me, but while waitKey() didn't work (supposedly) in openCV 2.4 it worked now. The application crashed due to getchar() existence. Debugger informed me only about threads exiting returning 0 in release mode, and only about that the my application exited returning -1. Or perhaps I'm doing something wrong in VS.

Thank you a lot, it's was really bugging me.